# Greping asterisk through bash

Tags: bash, unix, grep, cut, cat

I am validating few columns in a pipe delimited file. My second column is defaulted with '*'.

E.g. data of file to be validated:

```
abc|*    |123
def|**   |456
ghi|*    |789
```

2nd record has 2 stars due to erroneous data.

I teied it as:

```
Value_to_match="*"
unmatch_count=cat <filename>| cut -d'|' -f2 | awk '{$1=$1};1' | grep -vw "$Value_to_match" | sort -n | uniq | wc -l
echo "unmatch_count"
```

This gives me count as 0 whereas I am expecting 1 (for `**`) as I have used `-w` with grep which is exact match and -v which is invert match.

How can I grep `**`?

Comment: Also, note `unmatch_count=cat <file> | ...` is not going to work. If you want to store the output of a command in a variable, say `var=$(command)`.

Comment: Piping `cat` to `cut` and `cut`to `awk` and `awk` to `grep` is just crazy. `awk -F '\t' -v x="$Value_to_match" '$2 != x { a[$2]++ } END { for (s in a) printf("%8d%s\n", a[s], s }' filename` (guessing a bit there what you actually want).

Comment: Is no-one teaching shell scripting in college anymore? Good grief...

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is `grep` considering `**` a regular expression. To prevent this, use `-F` to use fixed strings:

```
grep -F '**' file
```

However, you have an unnecessarily big set of piped operations, while `awk` alone can handle it quite well.

If you want to check lines containing `**` in the second column, say:

```
$ awk -F"|" '$2 ~ /\*\*/' file
def|**   |456
```

If you want to count how many of such lines you have, say:

```
$ awk -F"|" '$2 ~ /\*\*/ {sum++} END {print sum}' file
1
```

Note the usage of `awk`:

- `-F"|"` to set the field separator to `|`.
- `$2 ~ /\*\*/` to say: hey, in every line check if the second field contains two asterisks (remember we sliced lines by `|`). We are escaping the `*` because it has a special meaning as a regular expression.

---

If you want to output those lines that have just one asterisk as second field, say:

```
$ awk -F"|" '$2 ~ /^*\s*$/' file
abc|*    |123
ghi|*    |789
```

Or check for those not matching this regex with `!~`:

```
$ awk -F"|" '$2 !~ /^*\s*$/' a
def|**   |456
```

Comment: i want to search only single star as mentioned in my 'Value_to_match' variable. However if i get any errorenous data as in this case i got '**' it can also be '***' or some other value my 'Value_to_match' variable should be able to catch it. The code was working fine for other values like alpha numeric value or single digit special character, however code failed to validate '**' scenario.

Comment: @Ishan your question is not clear. Edit it, describe what you want and what output you need. Then, I'll check again.

Comment: I just need to find out hte occurance of errorenous data. I this case it should give me output as 1 however it gives me 0

Comment: @Ishan this is exactly what my answer does.

Comment: you seemed to have hardcoded 2asterisk. 2 asterisk have appeared in the file as error, i will not be sure what kind of erroreneous data will flow in the file, i just know the corrct data that should flow i.e. single asterisk, if there is some thing other than this it should change the count in my variable.   I tried your code on applying the condition as /\*\*/ i am getting count as 1 however if i put it as /\*/ it gives me 3

Comment: @Ishan you are using `**`, which has an extended meaning as a regex. If you know that the *good* lines are those with just one `*`, then use my new approach, in which I print those: `awk -F"|" '$2 ~ /^*\s*$/' file`. Or `awk -F"|" '$2 !~ /^*\s*$/' file` to print the others. The rest of the output you want is still unclear to me.